# correlation coefficient bivariate normally distributed

Tags: correlation, bivariate-distributions

Suppose that X,Y and X,Z are bivariate normally distributed.
We have

$E(X)=0, Var(X)=10$, 
$E(Y)=0, Var(Y)=6$ and $ρ_{xy}=0.87$

Moreover,

$E(X)=0, Var(X)=10$,
$E(Z)=0, Var(Z)=4$ and $ρ_{xz}=0.87$

Indicating as K the joint distribution of Y and Z,i know from the theory of the problem i'm dealing with that K is *for sure* a bivariate normally distributed. I expect this will pose some constraint on the value of $ρ_{yz}$

Posted also here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414312/correlation-coefficient-bivariate-normally-distributed

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thank you. I rewrote formulas in a nicer style.